# Multiplication of odds vs. multiplication of probabilities

Tags: probability, statistics, bayes-theorem

I always believed that probabilities could be multiplied, until I encountered a statement in Machine Learning by Peter Flach about odds:

*"Bayes’ rule tells us that we should simply multiply them: **1:6 times 4:1 is 4:6**, corresponding to a spam probability of $0.4$."*

But converting to probabilities, $1:6 = 1/7$ and $4:1 = 4/5$.
Multiplying the probabilities we get $4/35$ ~$= 0.11$

Does Bayes' Theorem work differently for odds and probabilities? What seems to be the problem?

Comment: 4:1 cannot be a probability it is greater than 1.

Comment: @tpb261 4:1 is given as the odds, not probability.

Comment: Ok, I understood the OP differently.
But Bayes' rule is for probabilities not odds. For odds, they first have to be converted to probabilities.

Comment: @tpb261: You can state Bayes' rule as the posterior odds being equal to the prior odds times the likelihood ratio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose that the prior probability of a message being spam is $\dfrac{1}{7}$, and the conditional probability of a message triggering the spam filter is $k$ if it is spam but $\dfrac{k}{4}$ if it is not spam for some $k$.

Then, given the spam filter is triggered, the posterior probability the message is spam is $\dfrac{\frac{1}{7}\times k}{ \frac{1}{7}\times k+ \frac{6}{7}\times \frac{k}{4} } = \dfrac{4}{10}$.

This is equivalent to the same statement that if the prior odds for spam are $1:6$ and the likelihood ratio for the spam filter being triggered is $4:1$ then the posterior odds for spam given the  spam filter is triggered is $4:6$.

Effectively you have said  the earlier calculation is equivalent to $\dfrac{\dfrac{\frac{1}{7}\times k}{ \frac{1}{7}\times k+ \frac{6}{7}\times \frac{k}{4} }}{\dfrac{\frac{6}{7}\times \frac{k}{4}}{ \frac{1}{7}\times k+ \frac{6}{7}\times \frac{k}{4} }} = \dfrac {\dfrac{4}{10}}{\dfrac{6}{10}}$ or in a simplified form  $\dfrac{1}{6} \times \dfrac{4}{1}=\dfrac{4}{6}$.

Comment: After reading about prior and posterior probabilities, I could make sense of your solution. Thank you.

Comment: That should be "but $\frac{k}{4}$ if it is **not** spam for some $k$."

Comment: @Will Orrick.  Thank you - I only just spotted your comment

Answer (score 1):

The book calculate $$\frac{P(a|c)}{P(b|c)}=\frac{P(a)P(c|a)}{P(b)P(c|b)}$$
What you calculate is $P(a)\cdot \frac{P(c|a)}{P(c|a)+P(c|b)}  $, which has no meaning.

To get the value of 0.4:

$$P(a|c)=\frac{P(a)\cdot P(c|a)}{P(c)}=\frac{P(a)\cdot P(c|a)}{P(b)\cdot P(c|b)+P(a)\cdot P(c|a)}=\frac{\frac{1}{7}\cdot\frac{4}{5}}{\frac{6}{7}\cdot\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}\cdot\frac{4}{5}}=\frac{4}{10}$$

You should read about conditional probability and Bayes rule.